# Combobox esta carregando informações erradas de array

Tags: c#, json, array, winforms

Fiz uma aplicação em C#(WinForms) para carregar as marcas de acordo com o tipo de veiculo que for selecionado(carro, moto ou caminhao)em uma combobox. Coloquei em um botão o seguinte código:

```
private void btnCheck_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Object tipoVeic = cmbTipo.SelectedItem;
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            var url = "http://fipeapi.appspot.com/api/1/" + tipoVeic.ToString() + "/veiculos/21.json";
            var json = client.DownloadString(url);
            var serializar = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            var model = serializar.Deserialize<dynamic>(json);

            lblTipo.Text = tipoVeic.ToString();
            lblTipo.Visible = true;
            cmbMarca.Items.AddRange(model);
        }
```

Quando clicar ira carregar o combobox 'Marca'.
O que ocorre é que quando clico em carregar o combobox é preenchido com a informação (Coleção) repetidamente, conforme imagem abaixo.

[image: Combobox preenchido com a informação (Coleção)]

Talvez esteja faltando definir alguma informação do array, mas sinceramente não sei o que fazer neste caso. Se não ficou muito claro, me avise que tento especificar melhor nos comentários.

Valeu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você está deserializando o JSON de retorno como uma coleção de objetos anônimos e o controle ComboBox não sabe qual propriedade exibir, pois cada item do Combo é um array.

Analisando o JSON dessa API, é possível mapear o retorno para uma classe assim:

```
public class Marca
{
    public string fipe_marca { get; set; }

    public string marca { get; set; }

    public string key { get; set; }

    public string id { get; set; }

    public string fipe_name { get; set; }
}
```

Supondo, que você queira exibir a propriedade `marca` no combo para seleção, então seu código pode ficar assim:

```
var json = client.DownloadString(url);
var serializar = new JavaScriptSerializer();

var model = serializar.Deserialize<Marca[]>(json);

comboBox1.DisplayMember = "marca";
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(model);
```

Porém sugiro ao invés de usar o JavascriptSerializer, usar o JSON.NET (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) que é muito mais rápido e completo. Com ele você pode deserializar o JSON para um objeto anônimo, mais ou menos assim:

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, new[] {
    new {
        fipe_marca = "",
        name = "",
        marca = "",
        key = "",
        id = "",
        fipe_name = ""
}});
```

Comment: funcionou cara, usei o JSON.NET como você me passou, muito obrigado!